# Arguments On a Console eMbedded Visual C++ Application

Tags: c, arguments, windows-ce, evc

I'm trying to develop a simple application that will read some files, targeted for Windows CE. For this I'm using Microsoft eMbedded Visual C++ 3. This program(that is for console) will be called like this:

> /Storage Card/Test> coms file.cmss

As you can see, `file.cmss` is the first argument, but on my `main` I have a condition to show the help(the normal, how to use the program) if the arguments are smaller than 2:

```
int WinMain(int argc,char **argv) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        showhelp();
      return 0;
    }
}
```

But when I execute the program on the command-line of Windows CE(using all the necessary arguments) I got the `showHelp()` content. Then I've checked all the code, but it's entirelly correct. But I think that eVC++ don't use `argc` and `argv[]` for arguments, then I want some help on how to determine the arguments on it.

Comment: What does the signature/declaration of your `main` function look like?

Comment: @Reuben: Now I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The 'main' function of a Windows application can take one of a few different forms.  There's [`WinMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559(VS.85).aspx), there's [`main` and `wmain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299386(VS.60).aspx).  In your case, you've written a WinMain function that takes classic `main` parameters (i.e. `argc` and `argv`).

I'd recommend that you switch the name of your function to `main` and confirm that your Visual Studio project is correctly configured for the "correct" application entry point.

Comment: Are you compiling a console application or a Windows GUI application?

Comment: I've selected WCE Application.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular version of Visual C++, but Visual C++/Studio usually has an option to pick a 'GUI' (a.k.a. Win32) application vs. a 'console' application.  Windows GUI applications usually use the WinMain function; if this is what you're required to have, then you'll need to change the parameters of your main function to match the documentation for `WinMain` (i.e. lpCmdLine and others instead of argc/argv).

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply more details about the embedded platform.  Embedded platforms vary widely from desktop computers, especially about their resources such as file systems I/O, memory capacity and hardware layout (addressing).

For developing a WinCE application, you must confirm that the platform supports a file system.  Many embedded systems don't.

Next, you should research on how WinCE is set up to execute a C function:  does it use Windows (`WinMain`), `tmain`, `wmain` or `main`?  Also, you need to research how parameters are passed to the program.  Windowing programming is different than "console" programming.

Answer (score 0):

`WinMain` is defined as

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR    lpCmdLine, /* command line */
                   int       nCmdShow)
```

You'd probably want something similar to

```
if (sscanf(lpCmdLine, "%s", filename) != 1) {
  showHelp();
}
```